# Confidence Interval estimation for Cauchy distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation, confidence-interval

Considering a Cauchy distribution with scale parameter known(=1) and unknown location parameter, how can I estimate the confidence interval of the location parameter. Estimating the parameters using sample mean/variance does not work in the case of Cauchy distribution. How should I proceed?
[Question for reference- Q.110](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWlnP.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: You have a misconception.  Just because the expectation and variance of a Cauchy distribution are not well-defined does not preclude the ability to calculate a sample mean or using it as an estimator.  If you just look at the answer choices for your question, you will see that all of them can be easily calculated for a sufficient number of observations.  All you have to do is determine which of the choices have the nominal coverage probability.

Comment: @heropup Could you please elaborate? I don't understand how to proceed.

Comment: @heropup Do you mean to check the confidence interval using the cdf?